# Invalid roslaunch XML syntax

Tags: xml

So I've created two files: robot.launch and robot.yaml.
Robot.launch contains this:

Robot.yaml contains this:

nxt_robot:
  - type: touch
    frame_id: touch_frame
    name: my_touch_sensor
    port: PORT_1
    desired_frequency: 20.0

When I use roslaunch robot.launch I get:

root@joel:~/learning_nxt# roslaunch robot.launch
... logging to /root/.ros/log/ea9ca04a-da59-11e4-aa30-080027df9655/roslaunch-joel-21391.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

error loading  tag: 
    file does not exist [/opt/ros/electric/stacks/nxt/learning_nxt/robot.yaml]
XML is 
root@joel:~/learning_nxt#

Then when I run roslaunch robot.yaml I get:

root@joel:~/learning_nxt# roslaunch robot.yaml
... logging to /root/.ros/log/158aef32-da5a-11e4-aa30-080027df9655/roslaunch-joel-21400.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: syntax error: line 1, column 0
root@joel:~/learning_nxt#

What is wrong here? I input the contents of the file robot.yaml into http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/ and it says that there is nothing wrong with the text.

By the way, I am following these instrucutons: http://wiki.ros.org/nxt_ros/Tutorials/Getting%20started - steps (3.2), (3.3) and (3.4)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, [ROS has its own QA forum](http://answers.ros.org) that is very active. Questions like yours should be asked there.

```
Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: syntax error: line 1, column 0 root@joel:~/learning_nxt#
```

This error indicates that something is wrong in `.launch` file, not yaml. You should repost your question with the content of your launch file on ROS forum.